# Laravel: configuring to protect sensitive info

Tags: security, laravel

Hello, I have got the manual with me and I have gotten as far as I can but the last part is incomplete. The thing is about placing the database password in other files and then accessing them from the database.php file. This is so:

1) Here is the db file

```
                    'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'laraveel',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',

        ),
```

So now it tells me to create a file called .env.local.php, like this:

```
<?php

 return array(

 'TEST_STRIPE_KEY' => 'super-secret-sauce',

 );
```

and then from the db file accesing it like this

```
'key' => $_ENV['TEST_STRIPE_KEY']
```

I suppose he means this:

```
                     mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'laravel',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '$_ENV['TEST_STRIPE_KEY']',

        ),
```

But here is where I dont have the info. I dont know what I have to write next in the .env.php file, he says, create that file that contains the corresponding values for your production environment. I dont know at all what that is, what to write

Like the .env.local.php file, the production
.env.php file should never be included in source control

Comment: Don't wrap `'$_ENV['TEST_STRIPE_KEY']'` in a string. Write this instead: `$_ENV['TEST_STRIPE_KEY']` without the single quote `'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost right, the problem is that your wrapped `$_ENV['TEST_STRIPE_KEY']` in a string (with single quotes). Just unwrap it and everything will work as expected.

Change:

```
'password'  => '$_ENV['TEST_STRIPE_KEY']',  // Wrapped in a string
```

To:

```
'password'  => $_ENV['TEST_STRIPE_KEY'],    // No wrapped in a string
```

---

If you still experience problems, make sure you are in the right environment by running:

```
php artisan env
```

Comment: Thank you Rubens, but my question is what I have to do next when it says: create an .env.php file that contains the corresponding values of your production environment.